# Debug Mocha tests with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-2013, mocha.js

Most guides I found have old and unreachable links and examples.

I have some mocha tests and am trying to debug them with Visual Studio 2013.
Currently I've just ran them from the command line with the command:

`mocha tests --require tests/helpers/chai.js --reporter spec`

I've seen somewhere that I can add `--debug-brk` and then attach to process.

I'm getting `Debugger listening on port 5858` but I don't see a process with port 5858 in the attach window.

Am I missing some steps? I'm able to debug regular nodejs code on a NodeJS project (I have nodejs tools for visual studio installed)

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The debugging of Mocha tests in Visual Studio can be done using the Node.js tools for Visual Studio. However, there are a few things that need to be done. Open the properties of your mocha test file(s). Set their `TestFramework` property to `Mocha`. Also, add a `mocha.json` in your test dir to handle timeouts during debugging of tests. A minimal mocha.json has following contents (`timeout` being in milliseconds).

```
{
"ui": "tdd",
"timeout": 300000
}
```

After that, just rebuild solution and see if your test explorer (Test menu-> Windows-> Test Explorer) shows your tests. If yes, you can debug them like any other types of tests. The breakpoints you set in your mocha test files are hit.

YMMV. I did this in Visual Studio 2015. I don't see why this shouldn't work in VS 2013.

[image: Editing your mocha test file properties]